# Structuremap cause StructerMapConfigurationException("Operation could destabilize the runtime") only on some machines

Tags: c#, exception, structuremap

I'm using `Structuremap 3.0.2.115` as my `IoC container`
and defined following Factory class to get the `Usercontrol`s in my WinForm application(with .NET 4):

```
public class UserControlFactory
{
    public T Create<T>() where T : UserControl
    {
        return ObjectFactory.GetInstance<T>();
    }
}
```

I have this line of code to get a `UserControl`, too:

```
MyUserControl uc = new UserControlFactory().Create<MyUserControl>();
```

When I run the program on myself computer(Win 7) I get following exception:

> StructureMapConfigurationException was unhandled
>
> Attempting to create a build plan for concrete type Level4UI.ProductionPlanning.MyUserControl
>
> 1.) Attempting to create a BuildPlan for Instance of Level4UI.ProductionPlanning.MyUserControl  -- Level4UI.ProductionPlanning.MyUserControl
>
> 2.) Container.GetInstance(Level4UI.ProductionPlanning.MyUserControl)

with this inner exception

> Operation could destabilize the runtime.

But when I run the program on another computer(Win 7) it works correctly, without error.
In myself computer the .EXE file work correctly, too!

Does anyone knows, where is the problem?

Comment: Turn on Windows update or apply this patch: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2748645

Comment: @VahidN I installed this patch before, but the problem exists yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `UserControlFactory` to:

```
public T Create<T>() where T : UserControl
{
   return (T) ObjectFactory.GetInstance(typeof(T));
}
```

And the problem fixed!